# Show shop catalog description in another component using Bitrix

Tags: php, templates, bitrix

I need to show catalog DESCRIPTION in the component with name: `catalog.list`.

`$arResult["DESCRIPTION"]` isn't specified in this component. There is a list of goods in the `$arResult`.

How can I force the component to request a catalog `DESCRIPTION`?

There is no `catalog.section` component (which has `$arResult["DESCRIPTION"]`) on the page, because the site template I'm using is missing a lot of functionality.

Comment: What's the version of bitrix you use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `result_modifier.php` in your component template catalog.
Add

```
$res = CIBlockSection::GetByID($_GET["GID"]);
if($ar_res = $res->GetNext())
  $arResult['DECRTIPTION'] = $ar_res['DECRTIPTION'];
```

More info: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblocksection/getbyid.php

And enjoy.